# Ubuntu 12.10 not installing via USB stick

Tags: installation, 12.10, usb, wubi

I have a Dell Inspiron 15R (N5010) and I downloaded Ubuntu 12.10 onto a 4 GB memory stick. Nothing comes up about installation. The only thing that comes up is Install Ubuntu (F:) in AutoPlay. I open the view files and click the wubi.exe file and the Ubuntu Menu comes up. I then click Demo and Full Installation. Then i click Reboot Now. It reboots but nothing happens. I tried pressing the *Fn* and **F12** keys and nothing happens either. I'm not quite sure what to do now.. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a new laptop, probably [UEFI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) (the BIOS replacement) does not allow you to do it. I had the same problem with my new Samsung laptop. Before the secure boot was not turned off in UEFI (kinda BIOS, you can access it using F2 or something) I did not get any options about booting from CD or USB. So if you have a new laptop - turn off the secure boot and install Ubuntu!